# get_the_post_thumbnail wordpress 3.5

Tags: post-thumbnails

For some reason the following isn't loaded anymore in wordpress 3.5. Does anyone know how to fix the `get_the_post_thumbnail()` ?

I'm using the follow code:

```
echo "<div class='meta_apps'>";
echo "<a href='"; the_permalink(); echo "'>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-icon\">".get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr)."</div>";
echo "<div class=\"meta-title\">".$post->post_title."</div>";
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think `$post->post_id` works to retrieve the post's ID. I believe you want `$post->ID`. So that was probably your issue to begin with, though without seeing your `$attr` array, it's hard to say. Here's a reference for [`$post`'s properties](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return). In this case, [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) is the more appropriate function.

In your answer you posted for yourself, you're using [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) incorrectly. First off, you don't need to echo it; [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) will output the thumbnail. Side note: Any function in `WordPress` that starts with `the_` is almost always going to output something automatically. Second, You don't need to pass it `$post->ID` (again, using the wrong property). Third, the first property of [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) is the size, e.g. "thumbnail".

Comment: Thanks matthew, i'm not a programmer so these kind of basic stuff makes my head spin sometime. Thanks for your answer, it helps alot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

```
                echo the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id, array('class' => 'meta_icon')); echo "</div>";
```

Don't use 'get_the_thumbnail' but simply use the_post_thumbnail.

Comment: An echo is not required here, the the_post_thumbnail function already echos the image. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail